# Spring security - redirect to expiredUrl on concurrent login

Tags: spring-security

I have similar kind of issue like...I want to redirect to "/concurrent.htm?concurrencyError=true" when concurrent login issue occurs.

Configuration is as below:

> ```
>  <beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter"
>   class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter" >
>   <beans:property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
>   <beans:property name="expiredUrl" value="/concurrent.htm?concurrencyError=true" />
>   <beans:property name="redirectStrategy" ref="customForwardStrategy" />
> ```

but the issue is that it is getting redirected to "login.htm" irrespective of value defined in "expiredUrl".
I debugged and found the root cause is that, first my request to forward to concurrent.htm happens in concurrencySessionFilter but after that sequence of filter chain continues and since session will be null in authentication chain, it is getting redirected to "loginFormUrl" i.e., login.htm(This particular request arises in ExceptionTranslationFilter in handleException() method -> at lines shown below @sendStartAuthentication

```
else if (exception instanceof AccessDeniedException) {
        if   (authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication())) {
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point",
                        exception);
            }

            sendStartAuthentication(request, response, chain, new InsufficientAuthenticationException(
                    "Full authentication is required to access this resource"));)
```

So my previous request to "concurrent.htm" is overridden by next request "login.htm" and i m getting redirected to login page instead of concurrency.jsp page.

Do I need to add any configuration to stop further filtering once concurrency error happens in concurrency filter so that I can be redirected/forwarded to my  page that is configured ???

Comment: `ConcurrentSessionFilter` [returns immediately](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/session/ConcurrentSessionFilter.java#L110) after redirecting to the expired URL, so the filter chain does not continue. Check you are using are using an up-to-date version and if so, you'll need to be more specific about what actually happens. Check the log and monitor each request. Also make sure that your `concurrent.htm` is accessible to unauthenticated users.

Comment: Yeah, 'concurrent.htm' is accessible to all
>      <intercept-url pattern="/concurrent.htm*" filters="none"/>
>      <intercept-url pattern="/login.htm*" filters="none"/>

Comment: @Luke Taylor: Yeah, 'concurrent.htm' is accessible to all
     <intercept-url pattern="/concurrent.htm*" filters="none"/>
     <intercept-url pattern="/login.htm*" filters="none"/>
Filters getting continued even after concurrency error and an accessDenied exception is thrown in nxt filter(somewer in authentication as the original request('/fix.htm') is to authenticated users) and hence in Exception Translation Filter a new redirect to login.htm is happening.

Comment: @LukeTaylor: I m using spring security 3.0.5. Do I need to update to latest version(possibly 3.0.7) to implement concurrent login check.

Comment: Perhaps try it and see? 3.0.5 has known vulnerabilities so you shouldn't be using it in any case.

Comment: @LukeTaylor: I updated the spring- to 3.0.7 but no luck. I debugged further and what actually happening is - Logged as same user in 2 browsers and tried to operate in first session , an ajax call is being sent to url 'fix.htm' which is meant for authorized users and has defined set of filters associated - a redirect happens in concurrent filter but another ajax request is being sent to fix.htm where session is invalid, hence an AccessDeniedException is thrown in exception filter and a redirect to login.htm happens parallely...

Comment: @LukeTaylor: It seems both the above mentioned happen in separate threads(i said so bcoz flow is different at diff times when i debugged with debug points in eclipse) - a request to login.htm is the final one somehow and it is getting redirected to login page instead of concurrency page. Plz help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

I found the root cause for the issue.

### Rootcause:

The problem is not with the spring 3.0.5 version or some configurations. Its all due to small piece of code in one of my js file:

```
/* session timeout handling */
Ext.Ajax.on("requestcomplete", function(conn, response, options){
    //We can do nicer things here, like showing a login window and let
    //the user login on the same screen. But now we simply redirects the
    //user to the login page.
 if(response.responseText.indexOf("<html>") > 0){
    window.location = mFino.BASE_URL + "login.htm";
 }
});
```

Whats being done here is: Since our site is entirely built using extjs, we do send ajax requests, so if we send an ajax request lets say to "fix.htm"(once user logged in multiple systems at a time), the sequence of filters get invoked and when ConcurrentSessionFilter is invoked, a redirect happens to "concurrent.jsp" and filtering gets terminated(Ofcourse as I said when multiple requests are sent at a time, even when redirect happens in concurrency filter and the filter gets terminated, the other request will go thru the defined filters irrespective of first request gets redirected - then a AccessDeniedException is thrown in exception filter and a redirect to login.htm happens parallely - but this is not the root cause as I am facing issue even when only 1 ajax request is sent) So finally the concurrent.jsp content is sent as response to ajax request.

The content(i.e., response.responseText in

```
   Ext.Ajax.on("requestcomplete", function(conn, response, options))
```

will be a html page like ...

```
"<html>
    <head>
        <title>Adminapplication- concurrency issue page</title>......."
```

Since the condition is satisfied, the user is getting redirected to login page as per the code :

```
 if(response.responseText.indexOf("<html>") > 0){
     window.location = mFino.BASE_URL + "login.htm";
 }
```

Whats the intention in keeping this condition is: Generally the response for a ajax request will be a JSON or XML type for sample like :

```
 {success:true, message:'User name is xxx'}
```

so if at all, if they get the response other than this kind(say a html response) lets say due to session timeout, they are simply redirecting to **login.htm**.

This is what the root cause that is affecting my redirection to '**concurrent.htm**'.

### The solution I have comeup with for this is:

Changed the logic in **concurrenyHandler** to send json response instead of redirecting to **concurrency jsp** which will generate html response inturn ...as below:

Before:

```
@RequestMapping("/concurrent.htm")

public View concurrenyHandler(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        return new ModelAndView("concurrent");
    }
```

After:

```
@RequestMapping("/concurrent.htm")

public View concurrenyHandler(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("success", true);
        map.put("Error", MessageText._("Session Expired"));
        return new JSONView(map); //JSONView is our custom class which implements org.springframework.web.servlet.View and renders json object as string just like ..."out.write(this.jsonObject.toString());"
     }
```

In js file, changed the "on **requestcomplete**" function as below,

```
/* session timeout handling */
Ext.Ajax.on("requestcomplete", function(conn, response, options){
    //We can do nicer things here, like showing a login window and let
    //the user login on the same screen. But now we simply redirects the
    //user to the login page.
    /*if(response.responseText.indexOf("<html>") > 0){
    window.location = mFino.BASE_URL + "login.htm";
    }*/
 if(response.responseText.indexOf("Session Expired") > 0){
    window.location = mFino.BASE_URL + "login.htm?sessionExpired=true";
 }
});
```

and in the login.jsp, i ll check for sessionExpired=true condition and raise a alert with the message as below,

```
if('<%=request.getParameter("sessionExpired")%>'=='true'){
    alert("The session is expired due to timeout or because the same user logged in on another system");
}
```

changed spring settings as below:

```
 .......<custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" />
    <custom-filter ref="authenticationProcessingFilter" before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />        
    <custom-filter ref="customSessionManagementFilter" after="SESSION_MANAGEMENT_FILTER" />


    <session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" invalid-session-url="/concurrent.htm"/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="authenticationProcessingFilter" class="com.mfino.uicore.security.AuthProcessingFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas" />
</beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="customSessionManagementFilter" class="com.mfino.uicore.security.CustomSessionManagementFilter">
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter" >
    <beans:property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
    <beans:property name="expiredUrl" value="/concurrent.htm" />
</beans:bean>..........
```

Now i am able to display alert with the message in login page when concurrency exception occurs as required[previously the main thing I was worrrying abt is that I was unable to send request params like 'sessionExpired=true' to check the condition in login page and give alert as I was constantly being redirected to login.htm(without any such reqst params) irrespective of redirections that are done by spring handler].

Thanks to @LukeTaylor for guiding me on this !!!!